# Is there a method to simulate a key press in C++ in a way that no software could tell that i'm not actually pressing the key

Tags: c++, winapi, events, key, signals

I've tried SendInput and keybd_event, sometimes they work fine, but some running program doesn't recognize that i would like to press a key using c++ code. Is there a signal in c++ that is the same as the signal that emits when i press a key mechanically (so that no program can tell the difference)?

Or if it's not possible in C++, is it possible in any other programming language?

Comment: One example: mechanical key press using servo or something

Comment: This is outside of the scope of c++. Rephrase your Q.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=cTkx3cdO5rM Can do it.

Comment: You are going in the wrong direction: If it isn't possible using the lower level Windows API calls, then it's certainly impossible from a higher level, like a programing language, any language. If you need input to look like it's coming from a real device, write a device driver.

Comment: C++ has no functionality for this. Its nothing to do with any programming language. It's a platform question. Perhaps you should stop cheating at online poker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a signal in c++ that is the same as the signal that emits when i press a key mechanically (so that no program can tell the difference)?

That is exactly what `SendInput()` and `keybd_event()` are meant for.  [They inject events into the same hardware input queue that the actual keyboard driver inserts its events into](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773).  They get processed and routed the same way, so the majority of the system does not know the difference between a physical event and an injected event.

However, there is one area of the system that *does* know the difference: a low-level keyboard hook via `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL)`.  The [callback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx) receives a pointer to a [`KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644967.aspx) structure, whose `flags` member contains a `LLKHF_INJECTED` flag for injected events.  The callback can choose to discard events so they don't reach applications.

So it is likely that any app that is not reacting to your simulated keystrokes has been specifically coded to ignore injected input.

The only way to prevent that (without writing your own keyboard driver) is to write your own low-level keyboard hook and install it after other low-level keyboard hooks have been installed. This places your hook at the top of the hook chain. It can then skip the other hooks by simply *not* calling `CallNextHookEx()`.  Hooks are called in last-to-first order.  Per the documentation:

> If nCode is greater than or equal to zero, and the hook procedure did not process the message, it is highly recommended that you call CallNextHookEx and return the value it returns; **otherwise, other applications that have installed WH_KEYBOARD_LL hooks will not receive hook notifications and may behave incorrectly as a result**. If the hook procedure processed the message, it may return a nonzero value to prevent the system from passing the message to the rest of the hook chain or the target window procedure.

However, if an app is going to the trouble of using a keyboard hook to ignore injected events, chances are that it will likely also take hook order into account, such as by reinstalling its hook periodically to put it back on the top of the hook chain to avoid interference from other hooks.

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question.